# How does Java Streaming read actually work?

Tags: java, io, streaming

How does java input streams actually work? For example when you call inputstream.read(), how does Java break the file down into packets? Does java care about whether the file is .mp3, .doc, .txt, .mov ? How does the java io actually break all these different file types down into packets which can be streamed?

I greatly appreciate any answers on this topic.

Comment: What do you mean "packets"? Are you sure that you aren't confusing I/O streams with Internet streaming?

Comment: As stated, packets only apply to communication through sockets, and even there, you seldom have to care about them.  When data is being read directly from a file, though, the bytes in the file are read a certain amount at a time by your code.  If you wrap the InputStreamReader in a BufferedReader (even if you don't...at some low level) a certain amount of data is read from the file into a buffer (just a list of bytes) and your code's requests for data are pulled from the buffer so long as they're sequential enough.  That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 2):

> when you call inputstream.read(), how does Java break the file down into packets?

It doesn't. Files don't have packets.

> Does java care about whether the file is .mp3, .doc, .txt, .mov ?

No.

> How does the java io actually break all these different file types down into packets which can be streamed?

It doesn't. The files are *byte*-streams, and that is a property of the underlying resource and the operating system, not Java.

Answer (score 1):

When reading single bytes from streams, the `read()` method blocks until data is available.

Some streams may fetch data in blocks rather than byte-wise, but the block size completely **depends upon the implementation** (reading from compressed streams, reading from encrypted streams based on block ciphers, ...).
You can ask the stream how many bytes can be read without blocking (`InputStream.available()`), if somehow you need to know if and how much is buffered.

Java also provides a `BufferedInputStream` class which wraps any stream and can do buffered reads. The buffer size can be specified (default is 8 kB).
When using file streams, the file type has no effect on the buffering behaviour. It's recommended to always use `BufferedInputStream`/`BufferedOutputStream` when reading from and writing to files.